# How to use a variable value in items attribute of c:forTokens and c:forEach

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a jsp page which will read data from a text file, and will format it in tabular form.

The content returned from the text file into JSP is like:

```
ABC:::XYZ:::POR:::STV
asd:::fgh:::hjk:::lkj
zxc:::cvb:::nmn:::aaa
```

JSP PAGE:

```
<%! String content = MyFileReader.readData()); %>
<c:forTokens items="ABC:::XYZ:::POR:::STV" delims="::::" var="name">
<c:out value="${name}"/><br>
</c:forTokens>
```

Instead of `items="ABC:::XYZ:::POR:::STV"`, I want to use `content` variable in items attribute. `items="${content}"` is not working for me.

Comment: isnt it easier to return an array on MyFileReader.readData()?

Comment: I think you have to take help of c:set

Comment: It isn't a good thing to use scriptlets inside a jsp page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables declared in `<% scriptlets %>` or class members `<%! ... %>` are not part of EL scope. You need to move this value to either `page` `request` `session` or `application` scope, for instance using

```
<c:set scope="page" value="<%=content %>" var="value"/>
```

and then access it via `${value}` like

```
<c:forTokens items="${value}" delims="::::" var="name">
    <c:out value="${name}" /><br />
</c:forTokens>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try pageContext:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("content", MyFileReader.readData()); %>
```

OR

```
<c:set scope="page" value="<%=MyFileReader.readData() %>" var="content"/>
```